# Android: how to create Switch case from this?

Tags: java, android

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(CategoriesTab.this);

    adb.setTitle("Selected Category");
    adb.setMessage("Selected Item is = "+lv1.getItemAtPosition(position));
    adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
    adb.show();
}
```

This at the moment displays an alertbox when an item from listview is clicked.  I want to convert the alertbox to load a specific xml for each choices clicked.  How can i do this?
thanks for your help.

Comment: What does this have to do with a `switch` statement?

Comment: switch on the value that changes (position, as I read it from your code)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

```
switch(position) {
    case 0:
        setContentView(R.layout.xml0);
        break;
    case 1:
        setContentView(R.layout.xml1);
        break;
    default:
        setContentView(R.layout.default);
        break;
}
```

i hope this will do the job!

Comment: For default: is it needs "break"?

Answer (score 4):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.:

            break;
        case R.id.:

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

```
switch(position) {
  case 0:
    ...
    break;
  case 1:
    ...
    break;
  default:
    ...

}
```

Did you mean that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    String messageDialog;
    String valueOK;
    String valueCancel;
    String titleDialog;
    switch (id) {

    case id:
        titleDialog = itemTitle;
        messageDialog = itemDescription
        valueOK = "OK";            
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeView.this).setTitle(titleDialog).setPositiveButton(valueOK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "AlertItem");
            }
        }).setMessage(messageDialog).create();
```

and then call to

```
showDialog(numbreOfItem);
```

Comment: it will display the AlertDialog when list is clicked.I hope user513784 has implemented it.now he wants to redirect to specific activity by list click.